# IMDbPY installation fails

Tags: python, installation, imdbpy

I am trying to install [IMDbPY](http://sourceforge.net/projects/imdbpy/) in all sorts of ways and keep failing. The package is not pure Python (it has a few C lines) and I suspect that the compilation is the root cause (I'm on Windows).

### What I've attempted so far:

1. `pip install imdbpy`.
2. `easy_install imdbpy`.
3. Downloading [IMDbPY-4.9.tar.gz](http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/I/IMDbPY/IMDbPY-4.9.tar.gz#md5=5b071cd63d1804ed568741d2db8d12b5) from [Pypi Package Index > IMDbPY 4.9](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/IMDbPY/4.9), extracting the thing and then `python setup.py install`.
4. I've noticed that pip was trying to install the following packages: imdbpy, SQLObject, FormEncode, SQLAlchemy, decorator, Tempita. I've decided to try installing those packages one after the other by myself, starting with Tempita. I went to [Pypi Package Index > Tempita](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Tempita/0.5.1), downloaded the archive, extracted and then `python setup.py install`. It also failed.

### The output of each attempt:

#### `pip install imdbpy`:

```
Downloading/unpacking imdbpy
  Running setup.py egg_info for package imdbpy
    Created locale for: en it tr.

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distri
bution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'CVS'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.svn'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.hg'
    warning: no previously-included files matching 'CVS' found anywhere in distr
ibution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in dist
ribution
Downloading/unpacking SQLObject (from imdbpy)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package SQLObject

    warning: no files found matching 'examples\*.py'
    warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'tests'
Downloading/unpacking FormEncode (from imdbpy)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package FormEncode

    warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory '.'
    no previously-included directories found matching '**\.svn'
Downloading/unpacking SQLAlchemy (from imdbpy)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package SQLAlchemy

    warning: no files found matching '*.jpg' under directory 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching 'Makefile' under directory 'doc'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\build\output'
Downloading/unpacking sqlalchemy-migrate (from imdbpy)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package sqlalchemy-migrate

    warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*pyc' found anywhere in dist
ribution
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.hgtags'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'do
cs\_build'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): lxml in c:\python27\li
b\site-packages (from imdbpy)
Downloading/unpacking decorator (from sqlalchemy-migrate->imdbpy)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package decorator

    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'Makefile'
Downloading/unpacking Tempita>=0.4 (from sqlalchemy-migrate->imdbpy)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package Tempita

Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): distribute in c:\pytho
n27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.15-py2.7.egg (from sqlalchemy-migrate->imdb
py)
Installing collected packages: imdbpy, SQLObject, FormEncode, SQLAlchemy, sqlalc
hemy-migrate, decorator, Tempita
  Running setup.py install for imdbpy
    Created locale for: en it tr.
    building 'imdb.parser.sql.cutils' extension

    ====================================================================
      ERROR
      =====

      Aaargh!  An error!  An error!
      Curse my metal body, I wasn't fast enough.  It's all my fault!

      Anyway, if you were trying to build a package or install IMDbPY to your
      system, looks like we're unable to fetch or install some dependencies,
      or to compile the C module.

      The best solution is to resolve these dependencies (maybe you're
      not connected to Internet?) and/or install a C compiler.

      You may, however, go on without some optional pieces of IMDbPY;
      try re-running this script with the corresponding optional argument:

          --without-lxml        exclude lxml (speeds up 'http')
          --without-cutils      don't compile the C module (speeds up 'sql')
          --without-sqlobject   exclude SQLObject  (you need at least one of)
          --without-sqlalchemy  exclude SQLAlchemy (SQLObject or SQLAlchemy,)
                                                   (if you want to access a )
                                                   (local SQL database      )
          --without-sql         no access to SQL databases (implied if both
                                --without-sqlobject and --without-sqlalchemy
                                are used)

      Example:
          python ./setup.py --without-lxml --without-sql install

      The caught exception, is re-raise below:

    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__
file__='C:\\Users\\yonatan\\build\\imdbpy\\setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install
 --single-version-externally-managed --record c:\users\yonatan\appdata\local\tem
p\pip-czwg98-record\install-record.txt:
    Created locale for: en it tr.

running install

running build

running build_py

copying imdb\Character.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb

copying imdb\Company.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb

copying imdb\helpers.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb

copying imdb\linguistics.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb

copying imdb\Movie.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb

copying imdb\Person.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb

copying imdb\utils.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb

copying imdb\_compat.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb

copying imdb\_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb

copying imdb\_logging.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb

copying imdb\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb

copying imdb\locale\generatepot.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\locale

copying imdb\locale\msgfmt.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\locale

copying imdb\locale\rebuildmo.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\locale

copying imdb\locale\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\locale

copying imdb\parser\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser

copying imdb\parser\http\characterParser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\h
ttp

copying imdb\parser\http\companyParser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\htt
p

copying imdb\parser\http\movieParser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\http

copying imdb\parser\http\personParser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\http


copying imdb\parser\http\searchCharacterParser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\pa
rser\http

copying imdb\parser\http\searchCompanyParser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\pars
er\http

copying imdb\parser\http\searchKeywordParser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\pars
er\http

copying imdb\parser\http\searchMovieParser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser
\http

copying imdb\parser\http\searchPersonParser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parse
r\http

copying imdb\parser\http\topBottomParser.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\h
ttp

copying imdb\parser\http\utils.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\http

copying imdb\parser\http\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\http

copying imdb\parser\mobile\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\mobile


copying imdb\parser\sql\alchemyadapter.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\sql


copying imdb\parser\sql\dbschema.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\sql

copying imdb\parser\sql\objectadapter.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\sql

copying imdb\parser\sql\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\sql

copying imdb\parser\http\bsouplxml\bsoupxpath.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\par
ser\http\bsouplxml

copying imdb\parser\http\bsouplxml\etree.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\h
ttp\bsouplxml

copying imdb\parser\http\bsouplxml\html.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\ht
tp\bsouplxml

copying imdb\parser\http\bsouplxml\_bsoup.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parser\
http\bsouplxml

copying imdb\parser\http\bsouplxml\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\imdb\parse
r\http\bsouplxml

running build_ext

building 'imdb.parser.sql.cutils' extension



====================================================================

  ERROR

  =====



  Aaargh!  An error!  An error!

  Curse my metal body, I wasn't fast enough.  It's all my fault!



  Anyway, if you were trying to build a package or install IMDbPY to your

  system, looks like we're unable to fetch or install some dependencies,

  or to compile the C module.



  The best solution is to resolve these dependencies (maybe you're

  not connected to Internet?) and/or install a C compiler.



  You may, however, go on without some optional pieces of IMDbPY;

  try re-running this script with the corresponding optional argument:



      --without-lxml        exclude lxml (speeds up 'http')

      --without-cutils      don't compile the C module (speeds up 'sql')

      --without-sqlobject   exclude SQLObject  (you need at least one of)

      --without-sqlalchemy  exclude SQLAlchemy (SQLObject or SQLAlchemy,)

                                               (if you want to access a )

                                               (local SQL database      )

      --without-sql         no access to SQL databases (implied if both

                            --without-sqlobject and --without-sqlalchemy

                            are used)



  Example:

      python ./setup.py --without-lxml --without-sql install



  The caught exception, is re-raise below:



error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat

----------------------------------------
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\Users\\yonata
n\\build\\imdbpy\\setup.py';execfile(__file__)" install --single-version-externa
lly-managed --record c:\users\yonatan\appdata\local\temp\pip-czwg98-record\insta
ll-record.txt failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in C:\Users\yonatan\AppData\Roaming\pip\pip.log
```

#### `easy_install imdbpy`

```
Searching for imdbpy
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/imdbpy/
Reading http://imdbpy.sf.net/
Reading http://imdbpy.sf.net/?page=download
Best match: IMDbPY 4.9
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/I/IMDbPY/IMDbPY-4.9.tar.gz#md
5=5b071cd63d1804ed568741d2db8d12b5
Processing IMDbPY-4.9.tar.gz
Running IMDbPY-4.9\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\yonatan\appdata\loc
al\temp\easy_install-tubh5e\IMDbPY-4.9\egg-dist-tmp-nsslin
Created locale for: en it tr.
warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distributi
on
no previously-included directories found matching 'CVS'
no previously-included directories found matching '.svn'
no previously-included directories found matching '.hg'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'CVS' found anywhere in distribut
ion
warning: no previously-included files matching '.svn' found anywhere in distribu
tion

====================================================================
  ERROR
  =====

  Aaargh!  An error!  An error!
  Curse my metal body, I wasn't fast enough.  It's all my fault!

  Anyway, if you were trying to build a package or install IMDbPY to your
  system, looks like we're unable to fetch or install some dependencies,
  or to compile the C module.

  The best solution is to resolve these dependencies (maybe you're
  not connected to Internet?) and/or install a C compiler.

  You may, however, go on without some optional pieces of IMDbPY;
  try re-running this script with the corresponding optional argument:

      --without-lxml        exclude lxml (speeds up 'http')
      --without-cutils      don't compile the C module (speeds up 'sql')
      --without-sqlobject   exclude SQLObject  (you need at least one of)
      --without-sqlalchemy  exclude SQLAlchemy (SQLObject or SQLAlchemy,)
                                               (if you want to access a )
                                               (local SQL database      )
      --without-sql         no access to SQL databases (implied if both
                            --without-sqlobject and --without-sqlalchemy
                            are used)

  Example:
      python ./setup.py --without-lxml --without-sql install

  The caught exception, is re-raise below:

error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

#### `python setup.py install`

```
Created locale for: en it tr.

====================================================================
  ERROR
  =====

  Aaargh!  An error!  An error!
  Curse my metal body, I wasn't fast enough.  It's all my fault!

  Anyway, if you were trying to build a package or install IMDbPY to your
  system, looks like we're unable to fetch or install some dependencies,
  or to compile the C module.

  The best solution is to resolve these dependencies (maybe you're
  not connected to Internet?) and/or install a C compiler.

  You may, however, go on without some optional pieces of IMDbPY;
  try re-running this script with the corresponding optional argument:

      --without-lxml        exclude lxml (speeds up 'http')
      --without-cutils      don't compile the C module (speeds up 'sql')
      --without-sqlobject   exclude SQLObject  (you need at least one of)
      --without-sqlalchemy  exclude SQLAlchemy (SQLObject or SQLAlchemy,)
                                               (if you want to access a )
                                               (local SQL database      )
      --without-sql         no access to SQL databases (implied if both
                            --without-sqlobject and --without-sqlalchemy
                            are used)

  Example:
      python ./setup.py --without-lxml --without-sql install

  The caught exception, is re-raise below:

error in IMDbPY setup command: access to SQL databases wants to be able to remov
e imdb.parser.sql, but the distribution doesn't contain any packages or modules
under imdb.parser.sql
```

#### Trying to install Tempita with `python setup.py install`

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating Tempita.egg-info
writing Tempita.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Tempita.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Tempita.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'Tempita.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
warning: manifest_maker: standard file 'setup.py' not found

error: package directory 'tempita' does not exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.7 32 bit you could try out the binary package listed towards the bottom of this [page](http://imdbpy.sourceforge.net/downloads.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing Visual Studio Express 2008 (not 2010), it's free and provides the needed compiler.

You can also switch to ActivePython and use Pypm to install this package.